# Restoring scroll position on certain events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts-1

We have disabled 'Back' button functionalities in our Web application, and we are using certain HTML buttons to go back to previous page( that too for specified screens)
by invoking Action class methods. So my doubt is that, can the scroll position be restored only when pressing 'Back' button or at any other event?

PS : I'm not well versed in JQuery, so explain well.

Comment: but you are talking about the same page or you want to restore scrollbar position on page load??

Comment: Just add an event listener for when the window is loaded and set the scrolltop position to 0.

Comment: Sorry **@A.Sharma**, but I didn't get which event listener. Is it HTML event listener (document.addEventListener("click", function(){...) or java event listener?